GNU as: when to use '$'
After a long time I have to use the GNU assembler again. Ever since I had trouble with the '$'.
The manual just says:

3.6.2.1 Integers

A decimal integer starts with a non-zero digit followed by zero or more digits (‘0123456789’).
A hexadecimal integer is ‘0x’ or ‘0X’ followed by one or more hexadecimal digits chosen from ‘0123456789abcdefABCDEF’.
...


Doesn't say anything about a $.
But my GNU as 2.22 (from mingw32) insists on the following syntax (snippets):
.set   VIDEO, 0x10         # $0x10: no error but unknown sym
.set   SEG_386_ID,  0x60   # $0x60: no error but unknown sym
int    $0x11               # 0x11 --> size mismatch
movw   %bx, 0x0007         # $0x0007 --> invalid instr suffix
int    $VIDEO              # VIDEO --> size mismatch
movw   %ax, SEG_386_ID     # $SEG_386_ID --> invalid instr suffix

Looks like it's the instruction itself which demands or forbids the '$'.
I just didn't find the pattern:
Why do I have to say $VIDEO but have to omit $ in SEG_386_ID (and the .set of VIDEO)?

The dollar sign indicates an immediate addressing mode.  It is only correct when supplying immediate operands to instructions.

$ denotes an immediate operand to a machine instruction, i.e. an operand whose actual numerical value, encoded into the instruction itself, is the data that's operated upon by the instruction.  This syntax serves to distinguish an immediate operand from a memory operand, where there is an extra level of indirection: the value given is used as an address, and the actual data to be operated upon is obtained by performing a load from memory (and, in case of a destination operand, the result is stored back to that address).
The $ syntax is x86-specific (most other architectures don't use it) so it's not discussed in the manual's section on syntax for integers, which is architecture-independent.  Rather, you have to look in the section "80386 Dependent Features", which has a brief section on AT&T syntax, including the use of $ for immediates.  (Though all it says is simply "AT&T immediate operands are preceded by ‘$’".)
A typical example is addl $17, %eax, which simply adds the number seventeen to register eax.  (In Intel syntax this is simply add eax, 17.)  The $ distingushes this instruction from addl 17, %eax which would load a 32-bit longword from address 17 in memory, then add that value to register eax.  (Intel syntax would express this as some variant of add eax, dword ptr [17]).
In your example of movw %bx, 0x0007, the absence of $ means you are asking for the value in register bx to be stored in memory at address 0x0007.  This is mov word ptr [0x0007], bx in Intel syntax, and would correspond to the C statement *(short *)0x0007 = bx;.  (But is that really what you want?  Remember that AT&T syntax reverses source and destination operands.  If you wanted to move the numerical value 7 into bx, like Intel syntax mov bx, 0x0007, then you should write movw $0x0007, %bx.)
Likewise, int takes the interrupt number as an immediate operand, so we write int $0x10.  The syntax int 0x10 would correspond to a hypothetical "interrupt indirect" instruction, where a byte is loaded from address 0x10 in memory, and that byte is used as the interrupt number.  Intel syntax would be int byte ptr [0x10].  But x86 has no such instruction, so int 0x10 is rejected.  (I'm not sure why the error message is "size mismatch", which I agree is confusing.)
Immediates generally don't make sense as output operands.  Writing movw %bx, $0x0007 would be the equivalent of mov 7, bx or 7 = bx; there's no indirection, and you can't assign a variable value to a constant.  So this is nonsensical, and in particular it doesn't correspond to any x86 machine instruction, so it's rejected.
(The convention is different for jump-like instructions, where the operand is a code address.  jmp label is a direct jump, even though the address or displacement of label is encoded directly into the instruction and used as the new value for the instruction pointer, which might suggest that jmp $label would be more logical.  The above logic would likewise suggest that jmp label should be an indirect jump, where the new instruction pointer value is to be loaded from address label, but the AT&T syntax for that is instead jmp *label.)
All the same logic applies whether the operand is given by a literal number like 17 or a symbolic expression like SEG_386_ID whose value has been previously defined in the assembler (or will be defined at link time).  movw %ax, SEG_386_ID would store the value from register ax at address 0x60. As above, movw %ax, $SEG_386_ID is nonsense because it appears to assign a value to the constant 0x60.
The $ syntax is only used in actual machine instructions, never in assembler directives or pseudo-instructions like .set, .byte, etc, since in those cases there is no ambiguity to resolve.  .set VIDEO, 0x10 can only mean to assign the assembler symbol VIDEO the numerical value 0x10.  It can't mean to load a value from address 0x10 and use this as the value of VIDEO, because .set makes sense only at assembly time, whereas memory access is a run-time concept.
Since $ isn't needed syntactically here, I think that when you write .set VIDEO, $0x10 it attempts to set the symbol VIDEO equal to a symbol named $0x10, whose address is to be determined later by the linker.  Since no such symbol is ever defined, you get a link error.

The GNU assembler has rather poor error messages.  I think there are other cases where  trying to use a memory operand where an immediate is required complains of a "size mismatch", perhaps because a memory operand doesn't imply a size, and it checks that first or something?  Seems like a poor excuse if they care at all about human programmers (not just assembling GCC output), although probably they'd accept patches to improve the error messages, just nobody's bothered to do the work.  Clang's assembler might be better.

@PeterCordes: Yeah, feeding int 0x10 to clang's assembler gives "invalid operand for instruction" which is much more appropriate.

Symbol names can contain a $, so .set $fo$o, 0x10 does assemble cleanly, and nm shows the symbol table containing $fo$o.  Since you want to define VIDEO not $VIDEO, you need .set VIDEO, 0x10.   (mov $$foo, %eax lets you reference that symbol as an immediate.  mov "$foo", %eax lets you load from its address.  The quotes around the $ make it not special so it's not an immediate operand.)
